# Kafka Streams DSL folding hierarchical data

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Using Kafka Streams DSL, this is what I want to do:

Input message Serdes: Avro for both key and value
Key: Record with fields L1, L2, L3
Value: Record with value V (in this case an int)

What I want to do is collapse this heirarchy in such a way that the produced stream has the correct summed up value. For example,

```
Input:
L1   L2   L3  V
a1   b1   c1  v1
a1   b1   c2  v2
a1   b2   c1  v3
a1   b2   c2  v4
a2   b1   c1  v5



Output 1: (Data wanted at L1, L2)
L1   L2   V
a1   b1   v1 + v2
a1   b2   v3 + v4
a2   b1   v5

Output 2 (Data wanted at L1)
L1    V
a1    v1 + v2 + v3 + v4
a2    v2
```

Is there a way the Streams DSL would allow be this? Note that the key type changes across all outputs and I couldn't find a way to perform these rekey + aggregation (since rekey is esentially supposed to merge multiple values). While there might be ways to achieve this using the processor API or basic Kafka Consumer, want to check how to do this in DSL (if possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `selectKey()`:

```java
KStream input = builder.stream(...);
input.selectKey(/*create a new output record with only 2 attributes L1 and L2*/)
     .groupyByKey()
     .aggregate(...);

input.selectKey(/*create a new output record with only 1 attribute L1*/)
     .groupByKey()
     .aggregate(...)
```

Comment: Thanks! I also wanted to check if you have some thoughts about a derived use case of the above. If I want the end consumer to have the ability to show a consistent view of these changes, what would you suggest. An example of this being that for any change in the base value for (a1,b1,c1) to v1+d, this change along with the aggregate changes across all affected levels should be linked in some way (either by clubbing them in a single message or connecting the different messages).

Comment: Might be possible, but not easy to do.